# When i make bar chart using python library (pygal) it raises an error

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, pygal

when making a bar chart using pygal it raises an error which i don't understand but strange thing is that after these lot of errors still it works makes a bar chart.while pygal module is properly installed on my machine.
code is here:

```
import pygal
from random import randint

# rolling a dice 100 times
rolling_dice_result = list()
for i in range(100):
    result = randint(1,6)
    rolling_dice_result.append(result)

# how much time each number is occur
frequency_of_each_num = []
for i in range(1,7):
    result = rolling_dice_result.count(i)
    frequency_of_each_num.append(result)
#print(len(rolling_dice_result))
#print(frequency_of_each_num)

# Visualize the results.
hist = pygal.Bar()
hist.title = "Results of rolling one D6 100 times."
hist.x_labels = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
hist.x_title = "Result"
hist.y_title = "Frequency of Result"
hist.add('D6', frequency_of_each_num)
```

**Error Images**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Install Cairo library https://www.cairographics.org/

Comment: When i try to install Cairo through pip it generates an error
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cairo (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cairo"

Comment: install the cairo library from the link that I posted earlier.